# What happens after rethrowing again an exception inside catch clause?

Tags: java, exception

Well here I've seen this in API and other related questions:

```
try {

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new SampleException("Other IOException", e);
}
```

Which calls a new exception.

But now I have seen this example which calls itself. I'm trying to write the documentation and it seems it calls itself again.

```
try {
    statements;
}catch(TheException e) {
    //perform operations before exits;
    throw e; 
}
```

> Re-throwing the exception so that other handlers get a chance to
>   process the exception

I guess we can not add one more `TheException` after our `catch` exception! So in this case who is the other handler? I tested it and I realize even codes after catch clause are not compiled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two methods.

First one:

```
public void methodA() throws IOException {

    try {

        // methodWhichCanThrowIOException();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // //perform operations before exits;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Second one:

```
public void methodB() {

    try {

        methodA();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // //perform operations;
    }
}
```

See how method B calls method A. The exception raised originally inside method A is handler by method A itself, but once this is done, method A decides to throw the exception so other handlers get a chance to process the exception. Other hander as method A. Notice that method A can be in a different class, in a different layer.

For method A, throwing an exception is a nice way to inform method B that something happened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quiet clear. If IOException happens in methodA first it will get caught by IOExeption in its block and then when it come back to methodB (where it called methodA) again IOException happens in methodB. Is it right?

Comment: Exactly. When that happens, you should decide what to do in method B's catch block.

Comment: Now I understood what is happening. I guess If we don't catch the exception in MethodB, program will be terminated. Here is only one confusion for me. In methodA you already defined try/catch for IOException. Why  throws IOException is at the beginning of methodA? I mean here `public void methodA() throws IOException`!

Comment: You should declare what type of exceptions are thrown by the method. It is mandatory when you throw exceptions (using `throw`) inside the method. It is way to tell method B what type of exceptions it should take care when calls method A

Answer (score 2):

Try revising how exceptions work in JAVA and especially the `throw/throws` keywords and what is their difference.

Here is a nice [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) that explains that.

And you can always refer to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) for more info.

Referring to your question, your code probably doesn't compile because the method that the `throw` is in, probably doesn't `throws TheException`. You can add `throws TheException` in your method header for this to work, or you can try enclosing your `try/catch` in another `try/catch` that handles(catches) `TheException`.

Answer (score 2):

> So in this case who is the other handler?

It's almost exactly as if the `catch` clause had never been there - with the slight addition that *later* catch clauses won't be used. So for example:

```
try {
    methodWhichCanThrowIOException();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // This won't be hit for IOException
}
```

So:

- If there's another try/catch statement surrounding this code, the catch blocks *there* can potentially catch the exception
- Otherwise, assuming it's a checked exception, the method will have to declare that it can throw the exception (or a superclass) and the exception will propagate out of the method in the normal way

See [section 11.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) and [section 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) of the JLS for all the details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your example If the data type of the exception thrown matches IOException, it gets caught there. If not, the exception passes down to the second catch statement. Now I assume it caught there so  `throw e;` cause the second catch `Exception` happens. If yes what's the type of `e`? I think it is IOException again and Exception is not happening again!

Comment: @Bernard: Sorry, I don't see what you mean at all - where are you making an assumption, and about what? (The sentence starting with "Now I assume" really doesn't make sense to me.) If there's a specific situation which confuses you, please post a short but *complete* program in your question.

Comment: Sorry for making you confuse. I meant in your example the second catch clause will be executed?

Comment: @Bernard: Only when the exception thrown by `methodWhichCanThrowIOException` is not an `IOException`. (It could be another checked exception declared by the method, or an unchecked exception.) Basically, `catch` clauses can't catch exceptions thrown by other `catch` clauses within the same `try`/`catch` statement.